# R Round "object not found"

Tags: r

I am having trouble with round() in R. My goal is to subtract two sets of dates and store the result in two new columns.

The code I originally wrote gave me what I wanted but the new columns were not rounded. I'd like to round to the tenths place so I added in round(). Here is the resulting code

```
df_edit <- df %>%
mutate(
    enroll1 = Enroll - dob,
    discha1 = Discharge - dob,
    enroll_age = enroll1 / 365,
    discha_age = discha1 / 365) %>%
round(enroll_age, digits = 2) %>%
round(discha_age, digits = 2) %>%
select(
    Name, 
    RT, 
    Enroll, 
    Discharge, 
    dob, 
    enroll_age, 
    discha_age, 
    everything()
)
```

This code gives the error

```
Error in function_list[[i]](value) : object 'enroll_age' not found
```

The writing on round() that I've found tends to be simple and just a rehashing of the help information.

Because I am piping, I shouldn't need to state the data frame I am using when rounding, correct? I tried

```
 round(df$enroll_age, digits = 2) %>%
 round(df$discha_age, digits = 2) %>%
```

And got this error

`Error in function_list[i] : 
3 arguments passed to 'round'which requires 1 or 2 arguments
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'enroll_age'

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you want to give `round` it's own step in the pipeline. It should be called on `enroll1 / 365` directly inside the `mutate` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data, it is of course difficult to say which solution works best, but essentially you would need a second `mutate()` for your rounding or you can do the rounding already in the first `mutate`

```
df_edit <- df %>%
mutate(
   enroll1 = Enroll - dob,
   discha1 = Discharge - dob,
   enroll_age = round(enroll1 /365, digits = 2),
   discha_age = round(discha_age /365, digits = 2)
```